# Raw http response in golang

Tags: python, http, go, networking, python-requests

I have a request I'm making to an endpoint but however for some reason the response body only contains the last line of the response (the whole response is captured in fiddler). The same thing happens if I recreate the request in python using the requests module. However, I've noticed if I take the entire raw response in python, I am able to see all the lines (separated by multiple `\r`). I'm wondering if it is possible to view the whole raw response in go like with the `response.raw.data` method in python. In other words is there a way I can view the whole text response instead of it cutting off everything but the last line? If anyone knows as to why the last line is being cut off it will be appreciated greatly as well.

To clarify, this only happens with this single endpoint and I suspect the `\r`s in the response body may be the culprit but I am unsure. I've not seen this behaviour from any other http response.

edit: this is the code I'm using to view the response

```
bodyB, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
bodyStr := string(bodyB)
```

Comment: Done. The issue also happens when accessing the text response in python with `response.text`

Comment: In Go try this function https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpResponse, and make sure nothing else reads the body before that, if it does you need to reset the body yourself. You can take a look at DumpResponse's source to see an example of how to reset the body after reading it (https://golang.org/src/net/http/httputil/dump.go?s=8166:8231#L271) effectively allowing another subsequent read of the body.

Comment: Will try this when I get home in a bit thank you. Any idea what might be throwing the text response off across multiple langs? @mkopriva

Comment: @JordanAllen a badly formatted response

Comment: \r is a carriage return. It instructs your terminal to move the cursor (or carriage as it is called on a  typewriter) to the beginning of the line and overwrite previously written text.

Comment: That will be why then! the response is literred with \r's throughout after each line. Thank you for clarifying and thank you @mkopriva for the function for dumpin raw response. Should work perfectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\r` is a carriage return, but not a new line, so when you print it you are getting all of the lines, but they get overwritten each time.

You probably will want to do:

```
bodyB, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
bodyStr := string(bytes.Replace(bodyB, []byte("\r"), []byte("\r\n"), -1))
```